# rename files in the same folder using perl

Tags: perl, file-rename

I have some subtitles, but i need to rename all of those that do not have an specific tag.
subtitles in Spanish or any language they always have a tag at the end of the title.

> nameofthemovie(español).srt

Although English subtitles must have at the end (english) sometimes they don't have it.
so, i am looking for a script to rename all subtitles that do not contain parenthesis ()
and rename them with (english) but the extension change it from .srt to .txt  for both languages.

Example of input text:

```
nameofaserie.srt
nameofaserie(español).srt
```

Example of output:

```
nameofaserie(english).txt
nameofaserie(español).txt
```

I do have many subtitles and doing it manually would be tiring.
would be good if this possible with subfolders, because i have subtitles arrange them in subfolders for order, all of them under a folder called subtitles.

thanks for the help.

Comment: You are not asking a programming question, you are asking for a (free) programmer service.

Comment: Use a glob to find the files you want, use a regex to distinguish between files with and without parentheses, and perform the rename using `move` from `File::Copy`.

Comment: tlp, can you help me? do i start using the script with glob?  i found this example:  @many =  glob "{apple,tomato,cherry}={green,yellow,red}";

Comment: do i need to start : @many = glob "files.txt";  to tell glob find txt documents?

Comment: If you try it, what is the result? '

Comment: i found a program called advanced renamer, free utility. but i wanted to learn, but this is discouraging, anyways, i think i need a mentor, which is difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

As TLP has already said:

- Use a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to iterative of the files in your directory
- Use a regex to create your new file names
- Use [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) or [`File::Copy qw(move)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) change the file names